# Application Insights sdk for go is not sending availability test results

Tags: azure, go, azure-application-insights, azure-sdk

I am using following azure application insights sdk for go - `https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/tree/master`

and I wanted to use following **close** method from following file -

```
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/blob/master/appinsights/telemetrychannel.go
```

but it is not sending telemetry to application insights but when I am using **Flush** method then it is sending the telemetry. But the problem with flush method is that I have to put extra sleep method (with 2 or 5 seconds of sleep).

Please not I am directly calling the method (cant share full code snippet):

**appInsClient.Channel.Close()** and result which I am getting is empty channel.

if possible please share the code snippet that I can if I want to execute following method.

Comment: Here you can use a loop to check whether the result channel is closed It includes a short sleep **(`time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)`)** to reduce CPU usage during the waiting process.

Answer (score 0):

> If you're directly calling `appInsClient.Channel.Close()` and it is not sending telemetry to application insights.

It is due to the asynchronous nature of telemetry submission in the SDK.

- Introduces a short delay (1 second in this case) after flushing the channel and before calling the `Close` method.
- The delay allows time for the telemetry to be processed and sent. Adjust the delay duration based on the application's requirements.

Here is the code is to use a combination of the `Flush` and `Close` methods along with a short delay.

**Code:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/appinsights"
    "github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/appinsights/contracts"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize Application Insights client
    appInsClient := appinsights.NewTelemetryClient("YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY")

    // Run some operations or generate telemetry items
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        // Simulate some telemetry
        telemetryItem := contracts.NewTraceTelemetry(fmt.Sprintf("Telemetry message %d", i))
        appInsClient.Track(telemetryItem)
    }

    // Flush the telemetry channel
    appInsClient.Channel.Flush()

    // Introduce a short delay (e.g., 1 second) before closing
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    // Close the telemetry channel
    closeTimeout := 5 * time.Second
    resultChannel := appInsClient.Channel.Close(closeTimeout)

    // Wait for the result channel to be closed
    select {
    case <-resultChannel:
        fmt.Println("Telemetry items sent successfully.")
    case <-time.After(closeTimeout):
        fmt.Println("Timeout: Telemetry items may not have been sent.")
    }

    // Optionally, add a sleep to ensure the telemetry is sent before exiting
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

- This delay is introduced to allow the SDK time to process and send any telemetry items that are pending.

**Availability Check:**
[image]